# Create tables via content provider or access DBHelper directly? Other?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am building an Android app that uses a DB helper class and content provider used only for accessing the DB.  I noticed that when my app launches, it does not ever hit the onCreate() of my DBHelper class which has all of the DDL for the table creations, if they do not exist.

I have manually created one of the tables and have already confirmed that I can perform CRUD operations via my provider.  My goal is to have only the DBhelper class be accessed by the content provider and have the UI usilize the content provider for CRUD operations.

I feel like I am missing part of the chair here and could use some help in understanding how this process should work such that when my app launches, the system will check if the tables exist and create when they do not exist.

I have implemented my DBhelper class as a singleton, which there seems to be much debate about.

I understand that I do need to get a readable or writable db before the create operations can proceed, at least I think that is right.  The problem I am having is have not been able to piece together if I should do this by getting an instance of my db class from the onCreate of my MainActivity when the app launches?  Or, if there is something I should be doing in my content provider that will handle this when the app launches?  FYI - I do have my content provider registered within my manifest, as as mentioned previously, in my MainActivity onCreate(), I have successfully used my content provider for CRUD operations on a table I build manually.

Any direction here would be very much appreciated.

Here is my AppDB class

```
class AppDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "wgutrack.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String CTINE          = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ";
    public static final String PKA            = " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ";
    private static final String TEXT_TYPE     = " TEXT";
    public static final String INTEGER_TYPE   = " INTEGER";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP     = ", ";
    private static final String NN            = " NOT NULL ";

    // Implement AppDatabase as a singleton
    private static AppDatabase instance = null;

    private AppDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /**
     * Get an instance of the app's singleton db helper object
     * @param context The content provider's context
     * @return A SQLite DB helper object
     */
    static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AppDatabase(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // Create script for Terms table
        String sqlTerms;
        sqlTerms = CTINE + TermsContract.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + TermsContract.Columns._ID + PKA
                + TermsContract.Columns.COL_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + TermsContract.Columns.COL_START + INTEGER_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + TermsContract.Columns.COL_END + INTEGER_TYPE + NN + ")";
        Log.d("SQLQRY", sqlTerms);
        db.execSQL(sqlTerms);

        // Create script for Courses table
        String sqlCourses;
        sqlCourses = CTINE + CoursesContract.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + CoursesContract.Columns._ID + PKA
                + CoursesContract.Columns.COL_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + CoursesContract.Columns.COL_STATUS + TEXT_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + CoursesContract.Columns.COL_MENTOR_ID + INTEGER_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + CoursesContract.Columns.COL_START + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + CoursesContract.Columns.COL_END + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + CoursesContract.Columns.COL_START_NOTIFY + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + CoursesContract.Columns.COL_END_NOTIFY + INTEGER_TYPE + ")";
        Log.d("SQLQRY", sqlCourses);
        db.execSQL(sqlCourses);

        // Create script for term / course map table
        String sqlMap;
        sqlMap = CTINE + TermsCourseMapContract.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + TermsCourseMapContract.Columns._ID + PKA
                + TermsCourseMapContract.Columns.COL_TERM_ID + INTEGER_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + TermsCourseMapContract.Columns.COL_COURSE_ID + INTEGER_TYPE + ")";

        // Create script for Mentors table
        String sqlMentors;
        sqlMentors = CTINE + MentorsContract.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + MentorsContract.Columns._ID + PKA
                + MentorsContract.Columns.COL_FIRST_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + MentorsContract.Columns.COL_LAST_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + MentorsContract.Columns.COL_PHONE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + MentorsContract.Columns.COL_EMAIL + TEXT_TYPE + ")";
        Log.d("SQLQRY", sqlMentors);
        db.execSQL(sqlMentors);

        // Create script for Assessments table
        String sqlAssessments;
        sqlAssessments = CTINE + AssessmentsContract.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + AssessmentsContract.Columns._ID + PKA
                + AssessmentsContract.Columns.COL_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + AssessmentsContract.Columns.COL_DESC + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + AssessmentsContract.Columns.COL_TYPE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
                + AssessmentsContract.Columns.COL_COURSE_ID + INTEGER_TYPE + NN + ")";
        Log.d("SQLQRY", sqlAssessments);
        db.execSQL(sqlAssessments);

        // Create script for the Notes table
        String sqlNotes;
        sqlNotes = CTINE + NotesContract.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + NotesContract.Columns._ID + PKA
                + NotesContract.Columns.COL_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + NotesContract.Columns.COL_TEXT + TEXT_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + NotesContract.Columns.COL_COURSE_ID + INTEGER_TYPE + NN + ")";
        Log.d("SQLQRY", sqlNotes);
        db.execSQL(sqlNotes);

        // Create script for the Goals table
        String sqlGoals;
        sqlGoals = CTINE + GoalsContract.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + GoalsContract.Columns._ID + PKA
                + GoalsContract.Columns.COL_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + GoalsContract.Columns.COL_DESC + TEXT_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + GoalsContract.Columns.COL_DUE_DATE + INTEGER_TYPE + NN + COMMA_SEP
                + GoalsContract.Columns.COL_ASS_ID + INTEGER_TYPE + NN + ")";
        Log.d("SQLQRY", sqlGoals);
        db.execSQL(sqlGoals);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        switch (oldVersion) {
            case 1:
                // upgrade from version 1
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("onUpgrade() with unknown new version: " + newVersion);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "My goal is to have only the DBhelper class be accessed by the content provider and have the UI usilize the content provider for CRUD operations" -- why? Are you planning on other apps accessing this content via your provider? If not, then why not get rid of the provider and just use SQLite directly (or via Room or an ORM layer)? Using a `ContentProvider` purely for internal purposes is not a popular approach.

Answer (score 0):

> I noticed that when my app launches, it does not ever hit the
>   onCreate() of my DBHelper class which has all of the DDL for the table
>   creations, if they do not exist.

The `onCreate` method of the `SQLIteOpenHelper` class runs once when the database is created. It does not run every time an instance of the subclass is instantiated.

When developing an App the easiest ways of changing the structure of the database is to do one of the following (assuming that the data can be lost):-

- Delete/Clear the App's data from settings on the device and rerun the App.
- Uninstall and then reinstall the App and then rerun the App.
- utilise suitable code in the `onUpgrade` method that drops the table(s) and then invokes the changed `onCreate` method.

If you need to retain data, then you can use the `onUpgrade` method to ALTER tables within the limitations of [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).

You can check if a table exists by querying the **sqlite_master** table. This returns a cursor with 5 columns, namely :-

- **type**

  - **table** for tables
- **name** the name of the entity
- **tbl_name** the name of the table that the entity is related to.
- **rootpage**
- **sql** the SQL used to create the entity
- *(entity relates to the type e.g. table, index, view, trigger)*

> .... when my app launches, the system will check if the tables exist and
>   create when they do not exist.

So to check for tablex then you could use

```
SELECT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = 'tablex' AND type = 'table';
```

So you could have a method something along the following lines :-

```
public boolean doesTableExist(String table_name) {
    boolean rv = false;
    String[] columns = new String[]{"sqlite_master"};
    String whereclause = "tbl_name=? AND type=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{table_name,"table"};
    Cursor csr = yoursqlitedatabase.query("sqlite_master",columns,whereclause,wwhereargs,null,null,null);
    rv = csr.getCount() > 0;
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

- If you include the above in the DBhelper then `Cursor csr = yoursqlitedatabase.query("sqlite_master",columns,whereclause,wwhereargs,null,null,null);` could be `Cursor csr = this.getWritableDatabase().query("sqlite_master",columns,whereclause,wwhereargs,null,null,null);`

  - Often you will see `SQliteDatabase db = this.getWritabledatabase()` and then `db.query........`
  - you could then have something along the lines of `AppDatabase myDBHlper;` as a class variable and then `myDBHelper = Appdatabase.getInstance(this)` followed by `if (myDBHelper.doestableExist("your_table")) { ....... }` in the class (activity) where you want to check.

Of course simply using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ......` may suffice.

You could implement the checks etc by overriding the `onOpen` method of the class that is a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper (aka DBHelper) or the `onConfigure` method.